# How can I start my Elasticsearch service correctly on ruby on rails (V7)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, docker, elasticsearch, docker-compose

I am working on integrating elasticsearch to a ruby on rails apps (With elasticsearch-model gem). However, Whenever I send a request it returns the following error:

```
{"@timestamp":"2022-04-09T02:43:05.554Z", "log.level": "WARN", "message":"received plaintext http traffic on an https channel, closing connection Netty4HttpChannel{localAddress=/192.168.128.3:9200, remoteAddress=/192.168.128.6:38770}", "ecs.version": "1.2.0","service.name":"ES_ECS","event.dataset":"elasticsearch.server","process.thread.name":"elasticsearch[73415b48aadd][transport_worker][T#3]","log.logger":"org.elasticsearch.xpack.security.transport.netty4.SecurityNetty4HttpServerTransport","elasticsearch.cluster.uuid":"5_0N8RB0Roq4iE_nqniR2Q","elasticsearch.node.id":"3E0mbrjiSQKCjaZ5PopG2A","elasticsearch.node.name":"73415b48aadd","elasticsearch.cluster.name":"docker-cluster"}
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 154ms (ActiveRecord: 5.1ms | Allocations: 18974)

Faraday::ConnectionFailed (end of file reached):

app/controllers/api/v1/messages_controller.rb:33:in `puts'
app/controllers/api/v1/messages_controller.rb:33:in `puts'
app/controllers/api/v1/messages_controller.rb:33:in `show'
```

Piece of code that causes this issue :

```
    def show
        begin
        @message = Message.search(1)
        rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound => e
            render json: {message:  "Message isn't found"} , status: 400
            return             
        end
        puts @message
        render json: @message
    end
```

messages model file :

```
class Message < ApplicationRecord
  include Searchable
  belongs_to :app , foreign_key: 'app_token', primary_key: 'app_token', optional: true
end
```

Searchable file:

```
module Searchable
    extend ActiveSupport::Concern

    included do
    include Elasticsearch::Model

    mappings do  
        indexes :message_number ,type: 'integer'
        indexes :body ,type: 'text'
        indexes :app_token ,type: 'string' 
        indexes :chat_number ,type: 'integer'   
    end

    def self.search(_query)
        __elasticsearch__.search({
            query: {
                match: 
                {
                    body: "test"
                }
            }
            }).records
        end
    end
end
```

Notice that I use a dummy query to test connectivity that's all

Docker-compose service for elasticsearch

```
  elasticsearch:
    image: elasticsearch:8.1.2
    ports:
      - "9300:9200"
  app:
    platform: linux/x86_64
    restart: on-failure
    build: .
    command: bash -c "sh init.sh"
    volumes:
      - ".:/app"
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    depends_on:
      - elasticsearch
```

And finally elasticsearch initializer

```
Elasticsearch::Model.client = Elasticsearch::Client.new({host:'elasticsearch'})
```

I use an M1 machine and it caused lots of problems while working, so Idk if that's any relevant to that problem

Comment: Why localhost? I am using the docker image

Comment: it connects to a host and port local to the docker container...that's not the issue

Comment: Lol! Sorry ... I should read things better! Yes it's complaining about http vs. https. Okay, that's easily solvable. Either enable https in docker: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docker.html#docker-cli-run-dev-mode or disable https connection: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/javascript-api/current/client-connecting.html#connect-no-security

Comment: did either of those articles work for you?

Comment: Nop not really, I added these two lines to my docker-compose elasticsearch search and it worked

    `environment:
      - xpack.security.enabled=false
      - discovery.type=single-node`

Comment: Glad you got it sorted. Sorry for the bum steer I gave you at the start!